# How to change a value inside a third party library

Tags: java, android, reflection, code-injection

(You don't need to know android to help solve this question)

I am using a third party library in my android app. Call it libX. libX has a class named Constants in which they keep a number of constants. One such constant is used all over inside the library. But I need the value of that constant to be different from what it is. How do I change the value of that constant?

As illustration: I want to change the value of `badConstant` from `“I am too bad”` to `“I am good”`.

```
class Constants{
  public static final String badConstant = “I am too bad”;
}
```

I am open to any sort of creative solution. The thing is if I had a setter/constructor for the value all would be well. But right now there is no setter.

Also this library is obtained as a gradle dependency (if you care)

Comment: Do you have access to the original code? Then change it there and compile it yourself.

Comment: This might be worth looking into: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3301635/change-private-static-final-field-using-java-reflection

Comment: @TimoSta, no I don't. it's a grade dependency that I just pull in using `compile`

Comment: @NouvelTravay, can you find it in [MavenCentral](http://search.maven.org/)?

Comment: No it's a private vendor provided binary jar, I am thinking of the option of simply replacing the single class and then re create the jar. The problem is that each time I upgrade I would have to remember to exchange that single file.

Comment: This is, generally speaking, a bad idea. You have no guarantees about how this field is being used and your mucking around with it could result in unexpected behavior from this library. I would suggest communicating with the owner of the library and finding some other solution, which may or may not involve the library owner making some new API to support your needs.